# Does Windbg display addresses as virtual or physical when issuing a command such as

Tags: windbg

Would someone be able to clarify whether when you type a command at the Windbg command prompt are the 64 bit addresses displayed in the very first column virtual or are they actually physical addresses ?

```
lkd> uf nt!KiInitSpinLocks
nt!KiInitSpinLocks:
fffff802`127eb05c 48895c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx
fffff802`127eb061 48896c2410      mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rbp
fffff802`127eb066 4889742418      mov     qword ptr [rsp+18h],rsi
fffff802`127eb06b 57              push    rdi
fffff802`127eb06c 4883ec20        sub     rsp,20h
fffff802`127eb070 33ed            xor     ebp,ebp
fffff802`127eb072 488bd9          mov     rbx,rcx
fffff802`127eb075 c781a058000001000000 mov dword ptr [rcx+58A0h],1
fffff802`127eb07f 448d4520        lea     r8d,[rbp+20h]
fffff802`127eb083 488d8100590000  lea     rax,[rcx+5900h]
fffff802`127eb08a 89a998580000    mov     dword ptr [rcx+5898h],ebp
fffff802`127eb090 4889a9882c0000  mov     qword ptr [rcx+2C88h],rbp
fffff802`127eb097 8bf2            mov     esi,edx
fffff802`127eb099 418bc8          mov     ecx,r8d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on a physical machine (not a VM) and assuming that the physical memory is handled in a contiguous way (it needn't be in VMs), 0xfffff802127eb05c is at 18446735286 GB in your RAM.

But yeah, the documentation leaves it open. Just if you know that there is [`up`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/up--unassemble-from-physical-memory-) to disassemble physical memory, you'll find the statement

> The *up* command disassembles only physical memory, while the *u* command disassembles only virtual memory.